# How to Redirect when logged in(ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs

```
<Route path='/Signup' render={
          (props) => (
            <Signup {...props} Logged={Logged}/>
          )} />
```

I have a state with Islogged const and I want to rediect to home when logged or else render signup
how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ isLogged, ...props }) =>
  isLogged ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/Signup" />;


<ProtectedRoute isLogged={isLogged} path="/Home" component={Home} />
```

Use protected route for all routes that require login. If `isLogged = false`, then it will redirect to `/signup`